# Trying to understand matrix image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

On my linear-algebra lecture, we were given the definition of the image of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m,n}$ as follows:
$$ \mathrm{im} A = \{\vec y \in \mathbb{K} ^{m}: \exists \vec x \in \mathbb{K}^n . \vec y = A\vec x\}$$

I just can't wrap my head around this one. Could someone please tell me a less formal definition of an image, what exactly does it do, and how can I find it's base for a given matrix? Also, just by the way, how does matrix' image compare to a function's image? Maybe this will help me understand...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each matrix $A\in\Bbb K^{m,n}$ defines a function (specifically, a linear transformation)

$$T_A:\Bbb K^n\to\Bbb K^m:\vec x\mapsto A\vec x\;;$$

$\operatorname{im}A$ is just the range of this function $T_A$. You could just as well describe it as

$$\operatorname{im}A=\{A\vec x\in\Bbb K^m:\vec x\in\Bbb K^n\}\;,$$

just as you define the range of any function $f:X\to Y$ to be $\{f(x)\in Y:x\in X\}$. The image of $A$ is the column space of $A$, i.e., the subspace of $\Bbb K^n$ spanned by the columns of $A$; to find a basis for it, just find a maximal linearly independent subset of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Ah, I see! So in general, when thinking about images, I don't even have to worry about the formal definition. It's simply a subspace spanned by the columns. Yes, this is much easier for me to comprehend, thanks!

Comment: @Dunno: You’re welcome!